# Font Size Based on Char or Number Data

Tags: css, fonts, font-size

I am trying to find a way to display numerical digits as a larger font size than chars on a website (not my idea!).  The reason for this is to make the numbers stand out.

I have looked for a font that would satisfy this without coding but I could not find any.  Also, I don't want to slow down the website by having the font coverted to an image.

Does anyone have a solution to this ridiculous problem?

Comment: The easiest solution that comes to mind is to add a `<span class="numeric"></span>` to every numeric value, I don't think there is a pure CSS solution (short of building a custom font)

Comment: Can you add a class to the numbers manually, or do you need to scan the page (with javascript) and wrap all numbers you find in a class?

Comment: I'd have to scan certain fields and wrap the numbers in a class.  The website is displaying a sql query and only one or two of the columns needs this formatting.

Comment: Primarily, if numbers don’t look good, use a different font. Using different font sizes for different characters in text would cause uneven line spacing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to adjust the HTML, the simplest solution would be to wrap all the numerical digits in a `<span class="numerical">` and then use CSS to adjust the font-size. Like for example:

### HTML

```
<p><span class="numerical">1</span> to <span class="numerical">50</span>.</p>
```

### CSS

```
p {
  font-size: 100%;
}
.numerical {
  font-size: 150%;
}
```